# Typescript: Calling method from another method of current class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Supposably, I have this class:

```
Class ExampleClass {  
    public firstMethod(){
     // Do something  
    }  
    public secondMethod(){
     //Do something with invoke firstMethod
    }
}
```

How can I invoke first method from another correctly? (Simple "firstMethod()" is not working).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) :

```
public secondMethod(){
   this.firstMethod();
}
```

If you want to force the binding to the instance, use the => operator :

```
secondMethod= () => {
   this.firstMethod();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but on my code second methhod calling from callback function. `this`  indicate on data from calback context.

Comment: @VladDekhanov Edited with a solution to force the binding, as it seems to be what you want.

Comment: @dystroy @Vlad to be noted that `super` will not work with arrow functions

Comment: Is there in other alternative to "this", I my callBack function "this" says undefined after running the code.